# Shift + Click not working to take items from chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing Minecraft on a friend's PC the other day and noticed that when I pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click on an item in a chest, it automatically went to my inventory. How do I enable that on my own PC?

Answer (score 4):

This is a normal Minecraft feature. If it's not working on your PC, chances are you have touch screen mode enabled. You can disable it through Controls → Mouse Settings → Touchscreen Mode.

Note: If touch screen mode is enabled, holding <kbd>Click</kbd> and dragging items work in place of <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal Minecraft feature.  Have you tried it on your PC?  If it doesn't work there, then something is wrong with your setup.

Comment: I am not able to do it on my own PC, what could be wrong with the setup